# Computing the Fourier Transform of $\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+c\right)^{-1} f(x)$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

Let $\operatorname{f}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined s.t. $\operatorname{f}\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\right)$. When the minus one term indicates a reciprocal, how would one evaluate the Fourier transform given by the following integral for $c \in \mathbb{R}\ ?$.

$$
\hat{\operatorname{f}}\left(k\right) =
\frac{1}{\,\sqrt{\,{2\pi}\,}\,}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}kx}\,\,
\left(\frac{{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}x^{2}} + c\right)^{-1}\,\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$

We can assume that the integrand is finite at every point. Is there any fact that I may exploit about reciprocals when computing these Fourier transforms $?$. If no result holds in the general case, we can assume that $\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)$ is a simple trigonometric polynomial.

**Question:** Is there any way to represent
$\displaystyle\left(\frac{{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}x^{2}} + c\right)^{-1}$ by a Fourier multiplier $?$. If not, are there any other simplifications available $?$.

Comment: An expression like, for example, $(d/dx)^{-1}f = v$ is to be interpreted as $f = (d/dx)v$. This you can take the Fourier transform of directly using the derivative rule: $f'(x) \to ik\hat{f}(k)$. And then you can solve for $\hat{v}$ to get the inverse operator in Fourier space (which in this example tells us that the Fourier transform of $(d/dx)^{-1}f(x)$ is just $1/ik \hat{f}(k)$).

Comment: Thank you, I had hoped that this general approach would suffice.

Comment: @Talmsmen Were you able to arrive at a "multiplier?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ denote the operator $D=\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+c\right)$ and let $I=DD^{-1}=\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+c\right)\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+c\right)^{-1}$ denote the identity operator.

For any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{f\},\phi  \rangle&=\langle \mathscr{F}\{DD^{-1}f\},\phi  \rangle\\\\
&=\langle DD^{-1}f,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\langle D^{-1}f,D\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\langle D^{-1}f,\mathscr{F}\{(-k^2+c)\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\langle (-k^2+c) \mathscr{F}\{D^{-1}f\},\phi\rangle\\\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, in distribution we have

$$\mathscr{F}\{f\}=(-k^2+c)\mathscr{F}\{D^{-1}f\}$$

or alternatively

$$\mathscr{F}\{D^{-1}f\}=\frac1{c-k^2}\mathscr{F}\{f\}$$